# Very basic formula question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know that this site is usually used for complex math questions that I'll never understand, but I'm having a brain fart and whilst I am a programmer I certainly don't claim to be great at Math.

Two variables: `x`, `s`

If `x` > 0.1
    `s` = 1

Else `x` <= 0.004
 `s` = 0.1

How can I make the value `s` vary between 1 and 0.1 based on the value of `x`. For example, if `x` = 0.05, `s` needs to equal `0.5`.

Comment: There are several ways to do this, but I suspect you have something more specific in mind than what you asked. How did you come to the conclusion that $x=0.05$ should generate $s=0.5$?

Comment: That depends greatly on what exact relationship you want between $s$ and $x$.  You can, for example, set a linear relationship between them.  Are you aware that between any two points you can draw a line?  Have you any experience with coming up with the formula of a line given two points?  Try using the line that passes between $(0.1,1)$ and $(0.004,0.1)$ and using that to generate the values of $s$ given $x$ values between $0.004$ and $0.1$.

Comment: @Y.Forman I came to that conclusion as half the difference between `0.1` and `0.004` is `0.05`, and therefore my `s` value needs to be 0.5 (half)

Comment: "*Half the difference between $0.1$ and $0.004$ is $0.05$*".... but its not.  Half the difference between $0.1$ and $0$ is $0.05$.  Half the difference between $0.1$ and $0.004$ is something else depending on what exactly you mean, e.g. the average of them is $0.052$.

Comment: @jskidd3 But $0.5$ is not half the difference between $1$ and $0.1$. If you are looking for a linear relationship as JMoravitz suggested, when $x$ is midway between $0.004$ and $0.1$, $s$ should be midway between $0.1$ and $1$. So please clarify in what sense $0.5$ is "half" (since it's not half the difference)

Comment: @Y.Forman Apologies my small brain is getting confused. I am looking for exactly as you just described regarding linear relationship. "when x is midway between 0.0040.004 and 0.10.1, s should be midway between 0.10.1 and 1" -- exactly this is what I'm after

Comment: Assuming you don't care about learning how to do this with pen and paper, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=line+passing+through+(0.1,1)+and+(0.004,0.1)   If you do care about learning how to do this with pen and paper, googlesearch "how to find equation of a line given two points"

Comment: @jskidd3 Then I refer you to JMoravitz's comment above regarding drawing a line between two points. If you'd like further elucidation I'm happy to elaborate.

Comment: It's a simple ratio, based on `@jskidd3`'s comments.

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer but I need this in a formula rather than a line equation (probably used the wrong question tag). So if `x` = 0.004 `s` = 0.1, and if `x` = 0.1 `s` = 1, and then a value inbetween those if it's somewhere in the middle

Comment: That is exactly what a line equation is though, a formula.  The line equation I linked to earlier, lets call $\ell(x)=9.375x+0.0625$.  If you want all values of $x$ larger than $0.1$ to give the same result and all smaller than $0.004$, just combine $\ell(x)$ with those rules, making a piece-wise function $f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if}~x>0.1\\\ell(x)&\text{if}~0.004<x\leq 0.1\\0.1&\text{if}~x\leq 0.004\end{cases}$

Comment: @jskidd3 They are one and the same. If you have your line equation in $y=$ form and simply substitute the variable name $s$ for $y$, you have a formula for $s$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: For example, in the above, if we were to plug in $0.05$ for $x$, we would fall under the middle rule, so we use $\ell(0.05)=9.375\cdot 0.05+0.0625=0.53125$, so if we plug in $0.05$ for $x$ we get $0.53125$ for our $s$ value.  Meanwhile, if we plug in $15$ for $x$, we fall under the first rule, and so we get an $s$ value of $1$.

Comment: Or simply $f(x)=\max(0.1,10\cdot x)$ as it is not said that $0.004$ has to be the largest argument where the value is $0.1$.

Comment: @LutzL see jskidd3's first comment where it is *heavily* implied that he is looking for something akin to a linear relationship like we suggest above.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. Part of the problem is that I didn't know exactly what I was asking for but the submitted answer is what I was after.

Comment: So what, my function has $f(x)=0.1$ for $x<0.01$ which includes the range $x<0.004$, and is linear for larger $x$. In detail, $f(0.05)=0.5$ as requested. To add the cut-off at level $1$, modify to $\min(1, \max(0.1,10⋅x))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a linear relationship, you can scale the position arithmetically.

$x$ ranges from $0.004$ to $0.1$

$s$ ranges from $0.1$ to $1.0$

so if $x$ lies within that range,

$s = 0.1 + (1.0 - 0.1) * (x - 0.004) / (0.1 - 0.004)$

$s = 0.1 + 0.9 * 0.046 / 0.096$

$s = 0.53125$